# Accepting user input for Argparse arguments

Tags: python, argparse

How would I go about defining the float value of each argument with a user prompt? Currently I'm using default = x, but would rather allow a user to define a few variables before collecting them together and passing them to a function.

I thought I could do something like:

```
first = input("first float") 
second = input("second float")
third = input("third float")
```

...but I get: TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'float' and 'NoneType'",)

Here's code that works fine, but uses default = x vs. user prompt.

```
import sys
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv
    args.pop(0)
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Help")

    arg_parser.add_argument("--first", type=float, help="first value", default=1)
    arg_parser.add_argument("--second", type=float, help="second value", default=2)
    arg_parser.add_argument("--third", type=float, help="third value", default=3)
    args = arg_parser.parse_args(args)    
    whatever = WhateverWhatever(args.first, args.second, args.third)
    whatever.start()

class WhateverWhatever:
    def __init__(self, first = 1, second = 2, third = 3):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
        self.third = third
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: You have a typo- args.three instead of args.third under whatever =. Beyond that, I agree with John Kugelman. You seem to already have what you want.

Comment: How are you running this script?  On what system, or with what shell?  Normally we just use `python myscript.py --first 3 --second 33 --third 43`.  Do you understnd what we mean by commandline arguments?

Comment: @JohnKugelman The above code defines the floats with default = x, I'd rather have a user prompt. Normally I'd just throw in something like
    first = input("first float")
    second = input("second float")

...but I get: TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'float' and 'NoneType'",)

Answer (score 1):

The default parsing uses `sys.argv[1:]`

```
args = arg_parser.parse_args()
```

You could also provide a similar list

```
args = arg_parser.parse_args('--first 1 --second 23 --third 42'.split())
```

It's a good idea when testing `argparse` to

```
print(args)
```

to see what the parser produced.

A matching Namespace object can be produced with:

```
 args = argparse.Namespace(first=1, second=43, third=23)
```

Or `args` can be any object with the relevant attributes, `args.first`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your code in the console by writing

```
python <PythonFileName.py> --first=<first input> --second=<second input> --third=<third input>
```

you don't need to write an input method inside your code.

Answer (score -1):

Well that turned out to be extremely obvious.

```
import sys
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv
    args.pop(0)
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Help")

    arg_parser.add_argument("--first", type=float, help="first value", default=1)
    arg_parser.add_argument("--second", type=float, help="second value", default=2)
    arg_parser.add_argument("--third", type=float, help="third value", default=3)
    args = arg_parser.parse_args(args)  

    args.first = float(input("First value"))
    args.second = float(input("Second value"))
    args.third = float(input("Third value"))

    whatever = WhateverWhatever(args.first, args.second, args.third)
    whatever.start()

class WhateverWhatever:
    def __init__(self, first = 1, second = 2, third = 3):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
        self.third = third
```

Comment: If you're getting values from user input directly via `input()`, then all of the argument parsing is completely useless. Arg parse is for parsing command line inputs that are specified when the script is actually ran, not after it starts running.

Comment: I'm new to python but the above works for me within the context of my project. I'm jumping off from a pile of open source code that uses argparse from the get-go to set the variables when the script runs solo and just wanted a simple way to set the variables with a prompt vs. hardcoded defaults for testing purposes.

Comment: You should use an additional Python program in that case---the Python program can run, collect user input, and then call the function inside that main script. Otherwise if the program is run with variables, users will still be asked to overwrite them, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Very true. For my purposes it's not an issue (I'm the only user, this is a research project and I just need to validate some image capture algorithms IRL) but once it's ready for prime time I'll handle it as you suggest.